# when navigating to an url, I'm getting error: "urlopen() got an unexpected keyword argument 'headers' "

Tags: python, python-3.x, http-headers, web-crawler, urllib

I'm trying to navigate to a specific webpage, using urllib.request.urlopen.

```
hdr = 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; Win64; x64)'
my_url ='https://www.cms.co.il/catalog/products.aspx?keySearch=9SX3000I'
weburl = urllib.request.urlopen(my_url,headers=hdr,timeout=30)
```

I'm getting an error: `urlopen() got an unexpected keyword argument 'headers'`

I've tried to remove the header, but then I'm getting the error: `HTTP Error 403: Forbidden`

how to reach this page without getting an error?

Answer (score 2):

[`urllib.request.urlopen`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/urllib.request.html#urllib.request.urlopen) doesn't accept a `headers` argument, but [`urllib.request.Request`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/urllib.request.html#urllib.request.Request) does. You'll also need to specify the header key, e.g. `'User-Agent'` in this case.

```
from urllib.request import urlopen, Request

headers = {'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; Win64; x64)'}
my_url ='https://www.cms.co.il/catalog/products.aspx?keySearch=9SX3000I'

response = urlopen(Request(my_url,headers=headers),timeout=30)

print(response.status)
> 200
html = response.read()
print(html[:20])
> b"\n<!DOCTYPE html>\n<html>\n<head>\n<title>CMS Compucenter Ltd</title>\n\n<script>(function(w,d,s,l,i){w[l]=w[l]||[];w[l].push({'gtm.start':\r\nnew Date().getTime(),event:'gtm.js'});var f=d.getElementsByTagNam"
```

Comment: @D Malan - great! thanks